# Scroll Listview items even when , list_view_items do not fill its complete height

Tags: android

In List view when items fill its complete height then it becomes scrollable . can we make it scrollable even when,items of listview are less to fill its complete height.

Comment: how can you scroll it if everything is already on screen?

Comment: by making invisible things ! :)

Comment: when items just fills the listview then they are scrollable, but if they are scrollable then it provides good user experience .

Answer (score 1):

1. you can make a mini listivew, shrinking its height, then it's scrollable.
2. you can make a bunch of "blank" entries, that are invisible.  How you do this depends on the type of adapter you use.  E.g. array adapter, use blank "" text in the array.  Base Adapter, override getView and getCount, and for later positions set blank/transparent views. (you'll have to return them to normal in earlier positions due to view recycling).

Answer (score 0):

Just set a static layout height to the ListView?  Then it shouldn't wrap_content (or change depending on the length of the list.)  Instead it should be scrollable once the list is longer than the set layout_height.

Example:

```
android:layout_height="100dp"
```